# File Encryption and Decryption issue

Tags: c#, file-io, cryptography

I've been playing around with encrypting and decrypting files in VC# Express 2010.

All the tutorials and documentation I've seen require two `FileStream`s in order to encrypt the file - one for reading the unencrypted version, and the other for encrypting. When I actually wrote the code it kept throwing an error telling me it could not open the file because it was opened by another process at the output filestream.

I'm assuming that's because the file is opened by the input filestream. So that means I have to specify a different filename? So even after the operation is successful I'll now have the original unencrypted file in the directory and a separate encrypted version? Doesn't that defeat the point? Or am I doing something wrong here? My code is similar to this...

```
public string filename = "test.xml";
using (FileStream input = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (FileStream output = new FileStram(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
using (....all the crypto stream and transform stuff...)
{
    ...do the encryption....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right but it's not defeating the point. The (streaming) crypto APIs are intended to encrypt from Src to Dst. Think encrypting output while sending/receiving over a network etc. This keeps them simple, as they should be.

You complicate the issue by using the same file for Src and Dst. That is not totally impossible but like Copying a File over itself it needs some extra care.

Consider that in general, encrypting will increase the File size. So it is not safe to Encrypt a file in place. Decrypting might be, but I wouldn't risk it.

What you need is a Temp file and a rename action after completion.

Comment: This touches on on another problem: your file isn't safe if the attacker has access to your running computer. If you want to encrypt the file, you have to make sure that the unencrypted bytes never touch the hard drive. If you open your super secret business plan in word, all sorts of temp files are going to get written to the drive that you'll never be able to clean up. If you are looking to protect a file, you really need whole drive encryption.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can't create a separate filestream for both input and output on the same file, but you can create a handle that will read and write. The FileAccess enum has the flags attribute, so you'd just say `var handle = new FileStream(filename, FileAccess.Read | FileAccess.Write);` The obvious downside to this is you are going to have data lost if your encryption doesn't complete successfully.

I recommend having a separate file for the output though, atleast that way you won't lose data if your program breaks unexpectedly. If the encryption completes successfully, then delete the original and rename the encrypted file with the original file name.

Comment: Is this how other file encryption applications work? I've never seen a residual copy of the unencrypted source after an encryption operations. I should be outputting to a temporary file....create an if statement to monitor for operation success, and then if it is successful, THEN delete the original and rename the temporary in order to replace it? This ensures that the data is not lost?

Comment: This is how most apps worked back in the day. I'm not sure now. Temporary files will usually be set hidden, and may be in a temporary folder on the disk. The same idea is used in filesystem encryption - if you're moving a file to an encrypted filesystem, the original won't be deleted until the move is completed successfully. You must somehow keep the original data until you know the encryption is completed successfully, because it could be something simple like being out of memory, or a full disk which causes your app to fail.

Comment: If you really need to recycle the existing file, I'd suggest reading it in fixed block sizes (say something like 4096kb - something that will easily fit into memory). If, and only if each block completes successfully, overwrite the original block, but if not, output to a log file the position where the file is encrypted up to, and any potential data to help recover it. (ie, initialization vectors, keys, cause of error).

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.ReadAllBytes`. Then those bytes post to your encryptor, must work.

Answer (score 0):

There is another parameter where you can specify whether or not to allow another process to read or write to the file.

`openFile` is a string that represents the file name.

```
using (FileStream fileIn = new FileStream(openFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write))
using (FileStream fileOut = new FileStream(openFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Open))
```

This way, you can read and write to the same file.

```
while (myfileStream.Position < fileLength)
{   
    fileIn.Read(buffer, 0, 51200);    
    buffer = encrypt(buffer);    
    fileOut.Write(buffer, 0, 51200);                      
}
```

While this is easy and you don't have to write to a temporary file or have to move/rename etc, this can be really dangerous because if the encryption breaks suddenly for some reason, you will lose data!

Also, the `encrypt` function is something I implemented. `AesCryptoServiceProvider` along with `CryptoStream` can be used :)

Comment: I think your while condition is broken. But worse, the position of fileOut will start to overtake that of fileIn, and your file will be garbled beyond repair.

Comment: @Henk: Yes. You are correct. But the problem was in Mobile Devices, if anyone wants to encrypt a 500MB file, creating another 500MB file would be impossible due to resource constraints. I admit that this is dangerous and possibly faulty, but something of this sort has to done for resource constrained devices, right? Is there any other approach ? :)

Comment: The OQ doesn't mention Mobile, so your extending the problem here. You might be able to solve the situation w/o a tempfile by adding compression to the mix. But that's not guaranteed (it will break if the Src file is not compressable enough, ie already compressed).

Comment: @Henk: Thanx! :) I will start another question for this matter :)